# Closing a select tag using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown, html-select

I needed a custom  tag. So I designed it as:

```
    <span class="language-selector" id="myspan">
        <input id="display_language" value="EN" readonly>
        <span tabindex="-1" class="downarrow" id="myarrow"></span>
        <select size="10" id="selected_language" class="language_dropdown">
            <option class="language-option" value="EN">English</option>

            <option class="language-option" value="FR">French (Francais)</option>

            <option class="language-option" value="DE">German (Deutsch)</option>
        </select>
    </span>
```

I used custom CSS for the above. For JS, I used the following code to select the option from dropdown:

```
    var langSelec = document.querySelectorAll(
  ".language-selector .language_dropdown"
);
langSelec.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("change", function () {
    let children = element.parentNode.children;
    // console.log(children);
    var d = children[2].value;
    children[0].value = d;
  });
});
```

It works fine. For now, the dropdown only closes when I click outside the element or when I select an option from it.

**Problem:**

I need to close the dropdown when the element is clicked again. Can anyone help me in that please!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is what you wanted, but this line "closes" the <select> by setting the size to 1:

```
document.querySelector(".language_dropdown").setAttribute("size", 1);
```

Just add it after you set the value of the input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but all this does is makes the number of options 1. All I am seeing is one option "English"

Comment: Okay, what do you mean by closing then?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. By closing I mean collapsing the opened dropdown. Like when we select an option from a dropdown, it closes and that selected option is displayed in the box. In that sense "close the dropdown" on clicking the dropdown arrow on an opened dropdown